# django start server error with title auth_group' doesn't exist

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, virtualenv

guys i puled my project from github and i installed all required packages but after `makemigrations` or `runserver` commands i get error like below.

tying to comment '`social_auth`' and `social_django` ... and 
command like `python3 manage.py migrate --fake myprojectname zero`

or

```
python3 manage.py migrate --fake social_auth zero
```

or reinstalling packages dont work for me any idea???

error :

```
.....

......

   db.query(q)
  File "/home/mohammadreza/www/html/academy/uenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 277, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'academy.auth_group' doesn't exist")
```

this is installed app

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_jwt',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'social_django',  
    'rest_social_auth',  
    'api.v1.blog',
    'api.v1.store',
    'api.v1.accounts',
    'api.v1.manager',

]
```

requirment file:

```
amqp==2.2.2
appdirs==1.4.3
asn1crypto==0.24.0
billiard==3.5.0.3
cached-property==1.3.1
celery==4.1.0
certifi==2018.1.18
cffi==1.11.5
chardet==3.0.4
cryptography==2.1.4
cycler==0.10.0
defusedxml==0.5.0
Django==2.0.4
django-braces==1.12.0
django-cors-headers==2.1.0
django-filter==1.1.0
django-ranged-response==0.2.0
django-redis==4.9.0
djangorestframework==3.7.7
djangorestframework-jwt==1.11.0
gevent==1.2.2
greenlet==0.4.13
gunicorn==19.7.1
idna==2.6
isodate==0.6.0
kiwisolver==1.0.1
kombu==4.1.0
lxml==4.1.1
Markdown==2.6.11
matplotlib==2.2.2
mysqlclient==1.3.12
numpy==1.14.2
oauthlib==2.0.7
olefile==0.45.1
opencv-python==3.4.0.12
Pillow==4.1.1
pycparser==2.18
PyJWT==1.5.3
pyparsing==2.2.0
pytesseract==0.2.0
python-dateutil==2.7.2
python-memcached==1.59
python3-openid==3.1.0
pytz==2017.3
redis==2.10.6
requests==2.18.4
requests-oauthlib==0.8.0
requests-toolbelt==0.8.0
rest-social-auth==1.2.0
six==1.11.0
social-auth-app-django==1.2.0
social-auth-core==1.7.0
urllib3==1.22
vine==1.1.4
whitenoise==3.3.1
zeep==2.5.0
```

Comment: Try to do just `migrate` at first.

Comment: i did it say auth_goup table not exists... also i delete all migrations still have the error

Comment: Running `--fake` means your database and migrations will now be out of sync. It can be very difficult to get them back in sync, so it would probably be easier to start with a new db. The "table does not exist" error suggests that your [migration dependencies](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/migrations/#dependencies) might not be set correctly. As a hack you can manually run `manage.py migrate auth` first.

Comment: i started by new db .. and  tried manage.py migrate auth or social_auth .. any command will alert  auth_group table not exist

Comment: Have you tried running just `./manage.py migrate`, without any app_name?

Comment: yes i did @Ralf .

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me is, on an empty database after deleting files from migrations folder except **init**.py:

1. Go to projects urls.py and comment out all the paths
2. run  python manage.py migrate auth
3. Undo changes to urls.py
4. run python manage.py makemigrations
5. run python manage.py migrate

Comment: Really deserve an award. work like a charm when atempting to migrate using heroku

Answer (score -2):

u need to paste all error log for analysis as below.

```
...
  File "/opt/xxx/src_schedule/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from src_schedule import views
  File "/opt/xxx/src_schedule/views.py", line 16, in <module>
    __users_in_group = Group.objects.get(name=__app_group_name).user_set.all()
  File "/opt/zzz/env3.6.8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/zzz/env3.6.8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 402, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/opt/zzz/env3.6.8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 256, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/opt/zzz/env3.6.8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1242, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/opt/zzz/env3.6.8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 55, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/opt/zzz/env3.6.8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1100, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/opt/zzz/env3.6.8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/opt/zzz/env3.6.8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/opt/zzz/env3.6.8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/opt/zzz/env3.6.8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/opt/zzz/env3.6.8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/opt/zzz/env3.6.8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/opt/zzz/env3.6.8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 71, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/opt/zzz/env3.6.8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/opt/zzz/env3.6.8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 312, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/opt/zzz/env3.6.8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 224, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'auto_dev.auth_group' doesn't exist")

...
```

i found we cannot use some object as [__users_in_group = Group.objects.get(name=__app_group_name).user_set.all()] out the function. And fixed this error after move this source to function.